# Tortoise SVN: Resolve conflict using 'theirs'. What does it mean?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Can someone please explain the difference between the following two options of Tortoise SVN on conflicted files:

- Resolve conflict using 'theirs'.
- Resolve conflict using 'mine'.

On a side note. Why on earth no one has ever reported this confusing use of terminology as a bug?

Comment: The confusion is probably from not understanding the context of "theirs" and "mine"

Comment: I arrived here because of this confusion, albeit not in Tortise SVN but from the command line.   When updating on the command line, the option is given as "theirs-conflict", which is ambiguous as to whether selecting it will keep it in a state of conflict, or resolve it.

Comment: @pohl yes I recently discovered that command line option is worse.

Comment: It's even more confusing when you are merging and it switches terminology to "local" and "respository."  It's not the least bit clear to me which is which in this case.

Comment: I keep coming back to this page again and again. Why they didn't just say 'prefer local changes to repository ones' and 'prefer repository changes to local ones' or something similar which is logical and easy to comprehend. I know it's a little longer, but in this case less, most definitely is not more.

Comment: i'm not sure i see the problem, a far as language goes i can not think of a more clear way to resolve this. perhaps adding the word file on the end? 'theirs' and 'mine' are completely unambiguous - as is the meaning of 'resolve conflict using X' - although i agree that the command line option is very mildly confusing if you don't read help... perhaps i am being dim and there is an alternative interpretation? could you include this in the question?

Comment: Definitely ambiguous. Check out someone else's branch, then merge changes from a branch you made into it. See how clear yours vs mine seems then.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Resolve conflict using 'theirs' means that when you try to check in two files that have conflicting edits, SVN will discard your changes and use the other persons change instead.

Resolve conflict using 'mine' means that you will discard their changes, and use your version of the file instead.

Comment: Check out the image which explains a lot about this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tmerge-basics-conflicts.html

Comment: This answer doesn't address the ambiguity around theirs vs mine at all. I've just been asked to merge changes from a branch I've been working on into a branch someone else has been working on. In this case the changes that I consider 'mine' are the ones from my branch. However if I accept 'my' changes I will actually be discarding changes from my branch.

Comment: I don't see "Resolve conflict using `mine`" anywhere in the menu. Is there no way to ensure my changes are merged with their changes?

Comment: Yeah I don't understand this answer.  There is no 'other person'

Answer (score 42):

I wanted to add the whole list for further reference:

```
(e)  edit             - change merged file in an editor
(df) diff-full        - show all changes made to merged file
(r)  resolved         - accept merged version of file

(dc) display-conflict - show all conflicts (ignoring merged version)
(mc) mine-conflict    - accept my version for all conflicts (same)
(tc) theirs-conflict  - accept their version for all conflicts (same)

(mf) mine-full        - accept my version of entire file (even non-conflicts)
(tf) theirs-full      - accept their version of entire file (same)

(p)  postpone         - mark the conflict to be resolved later
(l)  launch           - launch external tool to resolve conflict
(s)  show all         - show this list
```

Answer (score 34):

I agree.

Seems to me that it would be more clear if it said:

- Resolve using repository (theirs)
- Resolve using working copy (mine)

Comment: In my opinion the best answers as conflicts might occur without a second person being involved (e.g. when using git flow with multiple branches).

Comment: Now what does "mark as resolved" do? does it use mine or theirs?!

Comment: It just removes the conflict flag and uses the current state of the merged file.  Normally you would view the conflicts and correct any issues, and then mark it as resolved.  The two options discussed in this question are shortcut options to resolve conflicts by only using your version or the version in the repo.  Doing this automatically sets it as resolved whereas when you manually correct a conflict you have to "mark as resolved".

Answer (score 7):

The SVN command line merge is confusing especially when merging a branch back into the trunk.  "My changes" are the ones I made in the branch, but *that would be wrong according to SVN*.  To really complicate things, SVN refers to the paths as SOURCE, TARGET, and HEAD in the command line help.

Here is the **simple answer**, if you run this merge statement **from the directory C:\Project1\Trunk**

```
svn merge -r 60:68 C:\Project1\branches\UpdatesToProject1
```

**"Mine" is the directory that SVN is being run from (C:\Project1\Trunk).**

"Theirs" is the directory that you are merging in and have specified on the command line (C:\Project1\branches\UpdatesToProject1)

It would be really really nice if SVN gave the paths that MINE and THEIRS refer to.

Comment: This answer should be higher. We use branch versus trunk and it gets very confusing.

Answer (score 6):

BuzzAnn is correct.  *mine vs theirs* is ambiguous, since what's in the repository might also be mine.  The unambiguous distinction is *repository vs local copy*.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that what is in the repository is no longer (solely) yours, it is shared with all that have access, then it might be clearer.

In this context:

"theirs" means "the team's shared code in the repository"
"mine" means (my)"working copy" (probably on local machine)

So:
"using theirs" replaces your working copy with the shared copy, discards your changes that exist on your local machine.
"using mine" deciding that the code in your working copy is what should be kept in repository, discarding what is currently in the repo.